# Cython exception propagation for cdef functions returning multiple values

Tags: python, exception, cython, cythonize

I have a `cdef` function returning an `(int, int)` tuple. I need to propagate exceptions and must therefore specify a return type for exceptions. Since my function never returns negative values, this could e.g. be `(-1, -1)`. With the standard syntax specified in the [documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#error-return-values), my function would then look like

```
cdef (int, int) myFunction(int arg) except (-1, -1):
    ...
```

However, when cythonizing the above function, I get the error

```
Not allowed in a constant expression
```

I am aware that I could just turn on looking for exceptions after every function call via

```
cdef (int, int) myFunction(int arg) except *:
    ...
```

but this seems inefficient to me.

How can I propagate exceptions for functions with multiple return values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: you cannot, at least not with the current version of Cython's cdef-tuples.

The underlying issue, that for such tuples the operator `==` isn't defined by Cython (this could be done obviously by comparing every entry - but in the current version it is not defined).

For a simple `cdef int myfun() except *` isn't actually that a big performance hit:

- If result is not `-1`, there is almost no overhead (only comparison to `-1`) at all.
- If result is `-1`, `PyErr_Occurred` is used to check for errors, which might mean quite overhead (all above for nogil-blocks)
- one can choose a critical value `X` via `except? X` and thus minimize/optimize the necessary number of  `PyErr_Occured`-calls.

However, if Cython knows no `==`-operator for a type (as with Cython's c-tuples), we are basically in `cdef void myfun() except *` case, that means there is no short-cut and `PyErr_Occured` must be always checked/called.

---

You might say that `==` is defined for Cython's tuples, because it gets compiled. But if you look at the generated code, you will see, that for the comparison Cython's ctuples are converted to Python-tuples.

---

I personally would first go with `except *` and see whether it really has a measurable impact. Because as `cdef`-function obviously can have Python-interaction, adding a little bit more might not hurt at all.

If it does, the best is probably to change the signature of the function, for example

```
 cdef  int myFunction(int arg, (int, int) *a) except -1:
      ...
      return 0
```

Even if this feels less smooth - it might be worth the hassle due to better performance.

Comment: Passing `int` pointers is a great idea! I think this is a perfect workaround.